# CGO and Logging

Tags: c, logging, go, synchronization, cgo

I'm about to adopt an enhaced logging library in a Go codebase, I've reduced my scope to [logxi](https://github.com/mgutz/logxi) and [log15](https://github.com/inconshreveable/log15). Even though they seem quite new, I like the [logfmt](https://brandur.org/logfmt) enforcement offered by them, although each has its advantages and disadvantages. Anyway, even bringing the simpler standard logging facility to the question, an issue remains.

I'm mixing Go and C++ a lot (through C bridges and CGO). I'm facing the issue of whether I should make Go callbacks for logging from C++ or logging straight from C++, which would make me miss the library pattern adopted in Go. In any case, let's say I'm talking about logging to stdout, I'm still unsure how to proceed with a best option about having synchronized output, since it's both Go and C land and I'll have some threads looping in C while some goroutines running on its own. By adopting the callbacks this may not be an issue, but it may be expensive... Also wrapping a logging facility for C is problematic since they generally provide a variadic API in Go.

Comment: What precisely is your question? You've written a lot about the drawbacks of what you're trying to do, but you haven't asked anything.

Comment: @JimB I may ask an exact question and get an correct answer for it, but it may not be what I was really looking for. General guidance in this scope, which I think is small, is one better answer.

Comment: @JimB this is the picture of the process of reasoning in my mind now. An experienced developer at the topic should know what's my need by looking at it. I believe the "picture" provides more information than me asking wrong questions.

Comment: Well, "general guidance" is off topic for SO, but it seems you have a good grasp of what you're trying to do. My opinion would be to log separately (go and cgo might as well be logically separate processes), and forgo synchronization between the two. If needed, a context id of some sort could be passed between the two and logged, so that log order could be resolved after the fact.

Comment: @JimB ah indeed, that's true, as I was too tied to logging to stdout, it just occurred to me too, right before you asked, that I may just forget about synchronizing and segregate go and cgo logging, I will be obligated to use other stuff than stdout but... Only thing is that it won't follow the same patterns and options. tks.

Comment: no problem. (also, if you do want discussion and/or opinions, the mailing list or IRC are probably more appropriate venues https://golang.org/help/)